# Bootstrap drop down menu closing on mobile devices, thought I fixed but did not

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown

I have the following menu

```
                        <li class="navigation-item dropdown">
                                <a href="" class="navigation-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dental SEO</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li  class="navigation-item"><a href="dental-marketing.html" class="navigation-link">Dental SEO Process</a></li>
                                    <li class="navigation-item"><a href="dental-seo-expert.html" class="navigation-link">Dental SEO Expert</a></li>

                                    <li class="navigation-item"><a href="why-dental-seo.html" class="navigation-link">Why Dental SEO</a></li>
                                    <li class="navigation-item"><a href="local-map-marketing.html" class="navigation-link">Local SEO</a></li>
                                    <li class="navigation-item"><a href="website-penalty-removal.html" class="navigation-link">Penalty Recovery</a></li>
                                    <li class="navigation-item"><a href="free-dental-website-marketing-review.html" class="navigation-link">Free Website Review</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="dental-ppc-social-marketing.html" class="navigation-link">PPC & Social</a></li>
                        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="email-marketing.html" class="navigation-link">Email Marketing</a></li>
                        <li class="navigation-item dropdown"><a href="" class="navigation-link dropdown-toggle">PCM</a><ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="navigation-item"><a href="practice-convertion-marketing.html" class="navigation-link">Practice Conversion Marketing</a></li><li class="navigation-item"><a href="dental-app-devlopment.html" class="navigation-link">Dental Mobile APP</a></li></ul></li>

                        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="dental-website-design.html" class="navigation-link">Web design</a></li>

                        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="contact-dental-seo-ltd.html" class="navigation-link">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="dental-seo-price.html" class="navigation-link">Pricing</a></li>


                    </ul>

                    <a href="#" class="pull-right buy-btn" data-modal-link="email-ticket">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Works fine on the desktop but not on mobile devices which appears to be a well known issue. The problem is I'm not so good with script so struggle to make the changes. Ive tried many different ways to fix it. At first the menu wouldn't even dropdown on the mobile devices so i believe i changed something in one of the main assets js files. I also changed the query version and added the following to the bottom of the page 
    
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
    
This enables the drop down menu to work but if you click on a link it just closes. 
Doe anyone have any ideas on how i sort this as I'm at my witsend and dont quite understand what I'm reading.

Thanks 
Dan

Comment: Please provide a working example, otherwise it's really  hard to help

Comment: hi, the domain is- dentalseoltd.co.uk. the weird thing is, you click the dropdown menu item first time and the menu closes. When you go back into the menu and click any drop down item again it will then navigate and you will have to repeat the open close and click once to get the menu items in the drop down to work. So you have to click into the menu twice for the drop downs to work. Not double click.

Answer (score 0):

fixed i added 
    .dropdown-backdrop {
       position: static;
       }

to bootstrap css and it worked